# How can I check if a symbol/MC is a child of another symbol/MC?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I'm using Adobe Animate HTML5 Canvas.  EaselJS would also apply.

How can I check if a symbol/MC is a child of another symbol/MC?

So a symbol/MC is added as a child of `lensParentLeft` in the following.  I then want to check if it is a child of that parent in a later function:

```
function onMouseUp(evt){
    var item = evt.currentTarget;
    item.drag = false;
    var pt = item.localToLocal(item.dot.x, item.dot.y, item.LFLensHolder.hitBox);
    if(item.LFLensHolder.hitBox.hitTest(pt.x, pt.y) ){
        item.x = item.LFLensHolder.x;
        item.y = item.LFLensHolder.y;
        item.lensParentLeft.addChild(item);
        }
}
```

The later function being the following, probably in the `if(item.drag)` condition statement:

```
function onMouseMove(evt){
    var item = evt.currentTarget;
    if (item.drag){
        var pt = item.parent.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);
        item.x = pt.x - item.offset.x;
        item.y = pt.y - item.offset.y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `contains` method. It does a recursive parent check up to the stage to find an ancestor.

https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html#method_contains

```js
if (someParent.contains(evt.currentTarget)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Note that `contains` will also return true if you check a symbol against itself.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if (item.parent == this.lensParentLeft) {
      //do stuff
    }
```

In this case I just wanted to change the parent of the symbol with an instance name of `item` from `lensParentLeft` to the stage.

So, I added `this.addChild(item);` inside the braces.